# How to pass model value on close modal popup?(Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have one bootstrap modal popup in angularjs.
My plunker is here : [Links](http://plnkr.co/edit/B50JTWXcgmFMq6oEPxit?p=preview)

My problem is that i want to get selected value on close popup not only on close button .if user want to close from out of area  like black background also need to get selected value.

**Code:**

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {

     // Here i want to get selected item like as above

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation for the [modal directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), the last paragraph mentions a `modal.closing` event that is dispatched on the modal dialog controller's scope when the modal is closed.

You can use this event to determine how the modal was closed:

```
$scope.$on('modal.closing', function(event, data) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data == 'backdrop click') {
    event.preventDefault();
    $scope.ok();
};
```

Note that the `data` passed with the event will be "cancel", "backdrop click", or the selected item (when they click OK).

In the specific case where the backdrop is clicked, you can prevent the modal from closing, and then invoke the "OK" code path.

Check it out in [this revised plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vb3Yzj5Vnwptgq5iwCsf?p=preview).

Comment: $on 'modal.closing' is  not working in ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js

Comment: @KishorP It looks like that's a [relatively recent addition](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/0ad208d6a0164517b85d8e8181e4a0fc98f4f5ec). You need to use a later version (like the one you used in your Plunkr). Note that the commit I linked to doesn't seem to have all the code to make this feature work, so there were likely other relevant changes made prior to this.